# Ansible looping list of shell commands and passing variables to the command?

Tags: loops, ansible

I am trying to figure out how to loop of shell commands but the commands contain variables. I am using this link as reference **https://github.com/VerosK/ansible-iscsi-target/blob/master/tasks/implementations/lio.yml**

The code is to loop thru the list of commands for each disk.

Here is the working code long way:::

```
---
-
  become: true
  gather_facts: false
  hosts: isci_ansible_centos01
  vars:
    iscsi_target_base: iqn.2017-11.local.centos7
    iscsi_targets:
      - wwn: iqn.2019-8.local.centos7
        disks:
        - name: 'iscsidisk1'
          device: '/dev/sdb'
          vgname: 'vg.iscsi1'
          lvname: 'lv.iscsi1'
          mode: 'block'
        - name: iscsidisk2
          device: /dev/sdc
          vgname: vg.iscsi2
          lvname: lv.iscsi2
          mode: block
  tasks:

    #targetcli '/backstores/block' create scsids1 /dev/vg-iscsi/lv-iscsi
    - name: Create backstore
      shell: targetcli '/backstores/{{ item.1.mode }}' create {{ item.1.name }} /dev/{{ item.1.vgname }}/{{ item.1.lvname }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks
      ignore_errors: yes

    #targetcli '/iscsi' create iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:disk1
    - name: Create target
      shell: targetcli '/iscsi' create {{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks
      ignore_errors: yes

    # targetcli '/iscsi/iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:disk1/tpg1/acls' create iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:node1
    - name: Create nodes
      shell: targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1/acls' create {{ iscsi_target_base }}:node{{item.1.name}}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks

    # targetcli '/iscsi/iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:disk1/tpg1' set attribute authentication=0 demo_mode_write_protect=0
    - name: Set Authentication
      shell: targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1' set attribute authentication=0 demo_mode_write_protect=0
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks

    # targetcli '/iscsi/iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:disk1/tpg1' set attribute generate_node_acls=1
    - name: Set geenerate_node_acls
      shell: targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1' set attribute generate_node_acls=1
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks

    # targetcli '/iscsi/iqn.2017-11.local.centos7:disk1/tpg1/luns' create /backstores/block/scsids
    - name: Create backing_store
      shell: targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1/luns' create /backstores/block/{{ item.1.name }}
      with_subelements:
        - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
        - disks
```

Here is what I want to do is covert it into::: but i think the variable item is getting confused. Is this method supported??? I Just want to know for future reference.

```
- name: Configure ISCSI using SHELL LOOP
  shell: {{ item }}
  loop:
    - targetcli '/backstores/{{ item.1.mode }}' create {{ item.1.name }} /dev/{{ item.1.vgname }}/{{ item.1.lvname }}
    - targetcli '/iscsi' create {{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}
    - targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1/acls' create {{ iscsi_target_base }}:node{{item.1.name}}
    - targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1' set attribute authentication=0 demo_mode_write_protect=0
    - targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1' set attribute generate_node_acls=1
    - targetcli '/iscsi/{{ iscsi_target_base }}:{{item.1.name}}/tpg1/luns' create /backstores/block/{{ item.1.name }}
  with_subelements:
     - "{{ iscsi_targets }}"
     - disks
```

BTW I had to use with_subelements to access items inside iscsi_targets. For some reason it wont let me use with_items and access using {{item.device}}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```yaml
    - shell: "{{ item }}"
      loop:
        - "AAA {{ item.1.name }} {{ item.1.device }}"
        - "BBB {{ item.1.name }} {{ item.1.device }}"
      with_subelements:
         - "{{ targets }}"
         - disks
```

Q: *"**Is this method supported?**"*

A: No. It's not possible to put 2 [loops](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_loops.html#loops) into one task.

Instead, it is possible to create a file with commands

```yaml
shell> cat commands.yml
- debug:
    msg: "{{ cmd_item }}"
  loop:
    - "AAA {{ item.1.name }} {{ item.1.device }}"
    - "BBB {{ item.1.name }} {{ item.1.device }}"
  loop_control:
    loop_var: cmd_item
```

and iterate(loop) *include_tasks*. The play below

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  vars:
    targets:
      - wwn: 2019.centos7
        disks:
        - name: 'disk1'
          device: '/dev/sdb'
        - name: 'disk2'
          device: '/dev/sdc'
  tasks:
    - include_tasks: commands.yml
      loop: "{{ targets|subelements('disks') }}"
```

give

```yaml
    "msg": "AAA disk1 /dev/sdb"
    "msg": "BBB disk1 /dev/sdb"
    "msg": "AAA disk2 /dev/sdc"
    "msg": "BBB disk2 /dev/sdc"
```

Comment: One last question how do i pass the targets.www or any variable outside into the commands.yml???? I tried using vars in your playbook it seems to work.. but did the exact same thing in the the one i am working one keep getting offending lines error messages...

Comment: The [scope](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#scoping-variables) of the variables is the play. The variables declared in the play will be available in the included tasks. Open new question and make it [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) if needed.